# piloting an UAV model in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, uav, simulator-gazebo, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
I need to pilot ah UAV model in gazebo simulation.
I used tha asctec_driver stack for making my UAV model with some adjustmet on it ([pelican model in gazebo)](http://answers.ros.org/question/2168/pelican-model-in-gazebo).

Now, i want that this UAV can fly.

thanks, in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12058/piloting-an-uav-model-in-gazebo./) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can now get a working quadrotor UAV model for gazebo via the [hector_quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor) stack. See also the announcement [here](http://www.ros.org/news/2012/03/announcement-of-hector-quadrotor-stack.html).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could take a look at [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gazeboquadrotor/files/) project. I know it isn't in ROS, but it's the closest to a working example of flying a quadrotor in Gazebo that I could find.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1